# Performance issues when animate on mobile with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, cordova, gsap

I am in the end of a mobile application development using AngularJS wrapped in a cordova webview but I have some issues with the panel transition animations.

I stopped trying with ngAnimate since I have strange behaviour with it. I'm actually using two divs who permanently stay in the DOM and wrap the current and next panel content I compile. I'm using the [GSAP Framework](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) to animate them, which is famous about its performances. But the animation are too laggy.

So I made a profiling frame by frame with the chrome dev tools timeline, and I saw that my scripting time was taken too long at the controller initialisation.

So I came up with two ideas : I can detect either the controller initialisation end (but I don't know how to do that in Angular), or I find a way to spread out the execution on multiple frames.

Can somebody lead me in a way ?

Here is the structure in index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="SparterApp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="panelCtrl" ng-controller="panelCtrl">
            <nav id="menu" ng-include="'views/menu.html'"></nav>
            <section id="currentPanel"></section>
            <section id="nextPanel"></section>
        </div>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Some others vendor scripts and my own angular scripts -->
    </body>
</html>
```

My panel controller :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('SparterApp')
    .controller('panelCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout, animService) {

        nextPanelHandler = $('#nextPanel');
        currentPanelHandler = $('#currentPanel');
        var protect = false;

        $scope.callbackNextPanel = function () {
            currentPanelHandler.hide();
            nextPanelHandler.attr('id', 'currentPanel');
            currentPanelHandler.attr('id', 'nextPanel');
            var buffer = nextPanelHandler;
            nextPanelHandler = currentPanelHandler;
            currentPanelHandler = buffer;
            protect = false;
        };



        /*
        **  Load the next panel in the 'section.nextPanel' element, compile it with angular, and execute the setted animation
        **
        **  templateUrl : the desired template url relative to the views folder or 'close' for closing popup
        **  options : an object with two attributes
        **      enterClass : the initialisation class for the next panel
        **      time : the time of the animation
        **  params : an object with all the arguments you want to transfer between panels
        */

        $scope.nextPanel = function (templateUrl, options, params) {
            // Prevent multi trigger
            if (!protect) {
                protect = true;
                var tl = new TimelineLite({
                    paused: true,
                    onComplete: $scope.callbackNextPanel
                });

                // Get a initialisation in a list
                var enterAnimFrom = animService.getAnimFrom(options.enterClass);
                enterAnimFrom.onComplete = nextPanelHandler.show;
                //Prepare the animation
                tl.fromTo(
                    nextPanelHandler,
                    options.time,
                    enterAnimFrom,
                    {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        scale: 1,
                        rotation: 0,
                        opacity: 1,
                        ease: options.ease
                    },
                    'start'
                );
                // Get the template to compile
                var newPanel = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'views/' + templateUrl})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    nextPanelHandler.html(data);
                    $scope.params = params;
                    $compile(nextPanelHandler.contents())($scope);
                    // Play the animation
                    tl.play();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert('An error occured with the next panel loading');
                });
            }
        };

    });
```

And the structure of a panel :

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="panel">
    <!-- The panel content -->
</div>
```

I can share the timeline if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I will share some of my own pains trying to get animation going reliably.  GSAP seems to have a harder time on full page animations on mobile.  I tried a number of things to speed it up since it pretty much dominates any other thing I try to animate over using strictly CSS.  I think due to the amount of page drawing it has a harder time lifting.  Similar post is on http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7149-tweening-large-divs-really-slow/.
I'm currently running CSS3 transitions on my site as a result but use GSAP to do the smaller lifting on anything else vs a whole page.

Regardless, whole page transitions depending on the page size and the type of transition gets onto a fuzzy grey area on tablets and phones as I've had more success with iOS than Android devices as far as performance.  FireFox has made some headway the last 8 months too.

Obviously, one selling point to GSAP is its going to work the same everywhere +/- a few frames per second.  CSS3 isn't, and you'll dispense of many hours (to the void) trying to get it.  I've also similarly failed over to JQuery.animate for browsers that don't support cssTransitions, but your reduced to margin equivalents which aren't as pretty but get it done.
I also believe there are cache limits on a lot of the tricks used to get gfx accelerating.  Super tall page going to a small page might result in some unexpected results.

I suspect this will get better as time goes on but its rough water right now.